# Changing from Standard Ubuntu13.10 to Ubuntu Gnome 13.10?

Tags: gnome, gnome-classic

On my desktop computer I run Ubuntu 13.10 with gnome-shell and gnome classic desktop as installed "out of the box" via Synaptic. Yesterday I installed Ubuntu Gnome 13.10 on my laptop and it looks and feels nicer than what I have here.

Would it be easy and low risk to move from the Unity distro + gnome-shell to the ubuntu gnome distro? I have three hd partitions: root, /home and swap.

Thanks -- Thomas

Comment: With 13.04 I found problems with both the standard Unity desktop and Gnome installed. Not sure if its still an issue with 13.10 but you can always back up your data to an external drive and do a Fresh install of Ubuntu Gnome then recover your personal data from the backup.  You also have the option to reinstall and tell it not to format your /home partition.

Comment: btw, there was no 3.XX. it started with 6.XX if i remember it correct

Comment: @aveemashfaq You don't remember correct it started with Warty Warthog (4.10) [see here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)

Answer (score 0):

it is not a problem. boot the live disk and in the partitioning menu select something else. then in the next tab, click the / partition and select change, and select as ext4 with a tick to format partition and select mount point as /. click the /home directory and do the same except for this time do not tick format the partition. the rest is the same install. it should not be a problem.